# React Router Open Link(react-router-dom) in Separate Window

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

It is ok, open in other tab,

```
<Link to={{ pathname: `/form-page/${objectid}` }}
target="_blank"> {"my link"} </Link>
```

but I need open in new window with options like width, height etc. It is possible on button click using width height options like that :

```
<Button type="link" onClick={() =>
          window.open(
            url,
            "_blank",
            "location=yes,height=%100,width=%100,left=0,location=0,scrollbars=yes,status=yes"
          )
        }>
    {"my button"}
</Button>
```

I need to do that with Link component above. How can I add these options to Link Component, what is the syntax for it? Or is it possible?

note :

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```